# Windows 7 Driver - Only Runs Once then Requires a Reboot

Tags: c, windows-7, drivers

Lately, I have been playing with drivers in Windows 7. So far, I have built a driver that can talk with a user mode application.
However, I keep having a problem starting and stopping the driver.
First, I install the driver and start it, and it works just fine. I stop it, and it stops fine as well. However, when I go to start it again, it errors out with an error 2 code "Can't find the file specified".

In order to fix this, I have to uninstall the driver, then reboot. Once I have rebooted, I can install it again, and run it once, and then the process starts all over.

So my question is how do I work around this problem? I really hate having to reboot every time I rebuild and test my driver, so I was wondering if I am doing something wrong in my build and deployment process.

I am using the standard DDK command line build for the build process, and I am using an app called OSR Driver Loader to load the driver. I can, however, use the SC command line to install it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I needed to delete the symbolic link that I was creating, and to delete the Device instance.

Here is the code I out into the OnUnload function:

```
// this deletes the symbolic link for the driver
IoDeleteSymbolicLink(&deviceLinkUnicodeString);

// this deletes the device
IoDeleteDevice(g_RootkitDevice);
```

So In full, I needed to have this as my OnUnload function:

```
VOID OnUnload(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject)
{
    // this deletes the symbolic link for the driver
    IoDeleteSymbolicLink(&deviceLinkUnicodeString);

    // this deletes the device
    IoDeleteDevice(g_RootkitDevice);
}
```